# PDO prepared statement against dB2 Database Failed when execute more than once in Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, pdo, db2, odbc, prepared-statement

I have PDO prepared statement as follows :

```
    $db2 = new PDO($dsn,$user_db, $pass_db);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_TO_STRING);
    $stm = $db2->prepare(" SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 from  LIBRARY.TABLE1 where COLUMN3 = :col3 ");

    #first execution
    $stm->bindParam(":col3", "JOHN" );
    $stm->execute();
    $result = $stm->fetch();


    #second execution
    $stm->bindParam(":col3", "LAURENCE");
    $stm->execute();
    $result = $stm->fetch();
```

The first execution is successful, but the second execution I get the error below :

```
SQLSTATE[HY010]: Function sequence error: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Function sequence error (SQLExecute[0] at \/build\/php7.0-AbaziF\/php7.0-7.0.33\/ext\/pdo_odbc\/odbc_stmt.c:260)
```

Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Environment :

```
PHP Version 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16
```

Comment: did you try [$stm->closeCursor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) between executions ?

Comment: Yes, Your solution works, thank you very much